# Extract tweet mention including including '@' but excluding the domain part e.g. @xyz.com using regex

Tags: python, python-3.x

Example Tweet `@twitteruser Please send an email to mediadesk@xyz.com`

Desired result: `@twitteruser`

My Code (re imported):

```
tweet = '@twitteruser Please send an email to mediadesk@xyz.com'
p = re.compile(r'(@[A-Za-z0-9]*)')
only_mention = p.findall(tweet)
print(only_mention)
```

My Code output: ['@twitteruser', '@xyz'].

I only need the Twitter username. Please assist. Thanks

Comment: Does the twitter name alwaus come at the start of the line? if so just add a `^` to your regex to tell it that your looking only for the `@` at the start of the line `r'^(@[A-Za-z0-9]*)'`

Comment: Or refine the regular expression to expect a non-word-character before the `@`.
E.g. using `[\b\W]`, c.f. https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By checking for a Non-word-boundary will do the trick: `\B(@[A-Za-z0-9]*)` is the RegEx you are looking for :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may add more restrictions :

- use beginning of string with `^` (and optionnal spaces `\s*`)
- no char before the `@` with a negative lookbehind `(?<!\w)`

A combination of all this : `^\s*(?<!\w)(@[A-Za-z0-9]*)`